# Включение директорий с хедерами Google Mock

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, gmock, google-test

Хочу разобраться во фреймворке для тестирования Google Mock. Использую под Windows 7 в MSVS 2017. Библиотеку собрал. Не получается подключить библиотеку и хедеры в настройках проекта.

У меня имеется солюшен с тремя проектами, один из них называется Main. В сабдиректории для проекта Main есть две директории, относящиеся к фреймворку GMock: Include и Libs. В директории Include находятся директории gmock и gtest с хедерами. В директории Libs лежит библиотека gmock.lib.

Настройки каталогов VC++ такие:
В Каталогах библиотек указан путь к директории Libs. В настройках линкера дополнительно указан путь к библиотеке gmock.lib.
В каталогах включаемых файлов указан путь к Include/gmock. Изначально я там указывал путь к корневому каталогу Include.

Проблемы такие:
С текущими настройками каталогов я не могу подключить файл gmock.h директивой #include "gmock\gmock.h". Получается только так: #include "Include\gmock\gmock.h". Почему требуется указывать каталог Include, если путь прописан к Include/gmock (или даже к Include)?

С текущими настройками при компиляции получаю ошибку: fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: gmock/gmock-actions.h: No such file or directory. Почему? Ведь этот файл лежит в директории Include/gmock.

Comment: Пути к инклюдам и библиотекам gtest и gmock следует прописывать отдельно. т.е. к путям инклюдов следует добавить две папки (предполагаю что папка googletest лежит рядом с папкой вашего солюшена) - `$(SolutionDir)..\googletest\googletest\include` и `$(SolutionDir)..\googletest\googlemock\include`, соответственно и библиотеки.